# How can I make a seamless transition between maps?

Tags: maps, mmo, world-design

I have a game where my character is plotted on a 100×100 tiles of 32 pixels width and 32 pixels height that makes a Map.

It's a 2dArray of [100X,100Y]. Whenever the character gets to a specific tile called "tile exit" it will load a new map and plot the character on it. So my whole world is made of different maps.

Of course, loading the new map whenever the user steps onto the tile exit means that it will itinerate through the 100X 100Y of the new map. This led to a small brief window of a black screen before the new map appears, so it's not a 'smooth' transition as if it were a one giant world, partially because the world is made of different maps.

How can I make it to create the illusion of a seamless transition between maps?

Here is the code where I load the map (mind it's Visual Basic but it's easy to read):

```
Sub SwitchMap(ByVal map As Integer)

    Dim y As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim tempint As Integer
    Dim ByFlags As Byte
    Dim handle As Integer
      Dim LoopC As Byte
    handle = FreeFile()
    If Musica = True Then
                    Sound3d.StopMidi
             End If
             '       Music_Stop 1
            engine.Light_Remove_All
       engine.Particle_Group_Remove_All

  engine.setup_ambient
    Open DirPath("Maps") & "Map" & map & ".map" For Binary As handle
    Seek handle, 1
            
    'map Header
    Get handle, , MapInfo.MapVersion
    Get handle, , MiCabecera
    Get handle, , tempint
    Get handle, , tempint
    Get handle, , tempint
    Get handle, , tempint

    'Load arrays
    For y = YMinMapSize To YMaxMapSize
        For x = XMinMapSize To XMaxMapSize
    '  MapData(X, Y).particle_group_index = 0


            Get handle, , ByFlags
 
            MapData(x, y).Blocked = (ByFlags And 1)
            
            Get handle, , MapData(x, y).Graphic(1).GrhIndex
            InitGrh MapData(x, y).Graphic(1), MapData(x, y).Graphic(1).GrhIndex
            
            'Layer 2 used?
            If ByFlags And 2 Then
                Get handle, , MapData(x, y).Graphic(2).GrhIndex
                InitGrh MapData(x, y).Graphic(2), MapData(x, y).Graphic(2).GrhIndex
            Else
                MapData(x, y).Graphic(2).GrhIndex = 0
            End If
                
            'Layer 3 used?
            If ByFlags And 4 Then
                Get handle, , MapData(x, y).Graphic(3).GrhIndex
                InitGrh MapData(x, y).Graphic(3), MapData(x, y).Graphic(3).GrhIndex
            Else
                MapData(x, y).Graphic(3).GrhIndex = 0
            End If
                
            'Layer 4 used?
            If ByFlags And 8 Then
                Get handle, , MapData(x, y).Graphic(4).GrhIndex
                InitGrh MapData(x, y).Graphic(4), MapData(x, y).Graphic(4).GrhIndex
            Else
                MapData(x, y).Graphic(4).GrhIndex = 0
            End If
            
            'Trigger used?
            If ByFlags And 16 Then
                Get handle, , MapData(x, y).Trigger
            Else
                MapData(x, y).Trigger = 0
            End If
            
      

                                       If MapData(x, y).charindex > 0 Then
                Call EraseChar(MapData(x, y).charindex)
            End If
            

MapData(x, y).ChangedTerrain = 0


For LoopC = 0 To 3
MapData(x, y).Offset(LoopC) = 0
Next
MapData(x, y).HasOffset = 0

                If ByFlags And 32 Then
                        For LoopC = 0 To 3
                    Get handle, , MapData(x, y).Offset(LoopC)
                    MapData(x, y).HasOffset = 1
'                    If MapData(Map, x, y).Offset(LoopC) = -14 Then MsgBox "fuck"
                Next
                End If
        'Erase OBJs
            MapData(x, y).ObjGrh.GrhIndex = 0
        Dim i As Byte
        For i = 0 To 3
        MapData(x, y).light_value(i) = -1
        Next
        
        
     

            
    
        Next x
    Next y
    
    Close handle
 '   engine.Light_Render_all
    MapInfo.Name = ""
    MapInfo.Music = ""
    
    CurMap = map
    
          If bRain = True Then engine.Engine_Meteo_Particle_Set (8)
          frmMain.MiniMap.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\MiniMapas\Mapa" & CurMap & ".jpg")

    
   
End Sub
```

---

Ok so i preloaded the left map here in an async mode. And you will notice that i'm changing to another map, even though i preloaded.

Perhaps it's de design level that is making to popup a tree ?

Here is the video that shows the problem:

https://streamable.com/csipce

Thanks in advance,
Luke

Comment: Have you tried loading in the adjacent maps to the current one prior to the transition? If done in parallel, you would already have them loaded and ready to go.

Comment: As GaleRazorwind already mentioned, why don't you try to load your map asynchronously bit by bit, you first load only parts that player sees before and then you can continue loading other parts while player is enjoying the game. Is there a particular reason this couldn't be achieved? I understand that many limitations are possible, like: 1. player sees whole map when entering a scene, 2. algorithm needs whole map layout (still in this case you can just generate layout separately from objects in a scene), 3. player can move really fast to other parts of a scene.